# Using Managed Certificate from Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, api-client-certificate

I have an API I need to call where the only auth is with a certificate, but it must be called from the Visualforce page to work properly as it returns a JavaScript object that will be called continuously as the user interacts (it is an ArcGIS service). Is there anyway to pass the certificate details the Visualforce page so that the certificate will be included in the real time requests?

Comment: Are you referring the PKI option as documented in https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/core-concepts/security-and-authentication/#authentication-patterns

Comment: No. There is a Layer 7 API gateway in front of the ArcGIS server that currently only accepts a certificate for authorization.

Answer (score 1):

In case others run across this in a similar search...
The basic answer is "no". The issue arose because certificate validation was a security requirement. This was solved by making an initial call from Apex with the certificate to get an OAuth token from behind the firewall and the pass that token to the Visual Force page. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it fit the enterprise security constraints within the time and budget constraints.